# How to set string with umlaut characters to wpf textbox?

Tags: wpf, textbox, special-characters

I am trying to set the `Text` property of a textbox in WPF with a string containing umlaut characters:

```
Textbox.Text = "!@#$%&*,ÖÄäü";
```

But the textbox only displays `!@#$%&*,` and omits the umlaut characters.

How to make the umlaut characters to appear?

Comment: Your code example works fine for a blank WPF project. And, there is no reason at all that certain characters wouldn't display when set to the `Text` property like that, except that the font you're using simply doesn't include glyphs for those characters. Use a different font. See proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to save the file with the `Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001` encoding (File->Save As->Save with Encoding in Visual Studio) or look up the unicode for the character in the `Character Map` application in Windows.

For `ü`, it's `00FC` for example:

```
Textbox.Text = "\u00FC";
```